# Nested query in subsonic

Tags: nested, subsonic

How do I form this query using subsonic?

```
SELECT A.categoryname,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM items B
     WHERE a.categoryid = b.categoryid) AS TOT
FROM category A
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT A.categoryname, COUNT(B.categoryid) AS TOT
FROM category A LEFT OUTER JOIN items B ON A.categoryid = B.categoryid
GROUP BY A.id, A.categoryname
```

If no categories have the same name, you can omit the `A.id` column.

Then use SubSonic similar to this (the exact syntax may vary...):

```
DAL.DB.Select(
    Aggregate.GroupBy(DAL.A.categorynameColumn),
    Aggregate.GroupBy(DAL.A.idColumn)
    Aggregate.Count(DAL.B.categoryidColumn, "Tot")
    )
.From<DAL.A>().LeftOuterJoin(DAL.B.categoryidColumn, DAL.A.categoryidColumn)
```